# Ruby on Rails, xmpp4r 0.5 and no such file to load -- xmpp4r

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, require, xmpp4r

have ruby 1.8.7, gem 1.3.7 and rails 3.0.6. I wanted to add xmpp4r to my project, but i got error just i `require` this gem. I'm install this gem using `gem install xmpp4r`. Installation seems successful.But, why error then appear?
P.S. if in console enter the irb and execute `require "xmpp4r"` result will be `true`.
P.S.S. OS is Fedora

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails 3 uses [Bundler](http://gembundler.com/) to manage gem dependencies. When you start a rails 3 application, bundler sets up the require path to only include those gems you have specified in your `Gemfile` file, and their dependencies; it's not enough to just have the gem installed on your system.

In order to get this working, simply add this line to your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'xmpp4r'
```